# appium push_file failed with strange error

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

So i am using last `appium` version 1.13.0 and i have read `android` device and i want to push file from my computer (`windows 10`) into my device.

In my windows file explorer i can see my device under `This PC\P00A\Internal shared storage` and inside this path i can see all my folders.

So i try to push file this way:

```
self.driver.push_file(
                '/Internal shared storage/Pictures/file.csv',
                source_path=r'C:\Users\ran\Desktop\file.csv')
```

Pictures file exist in my android device.

And this is the error:

> Exception occurred: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred
>   while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec.
>   Original error: 'Command
>   'C:\Users\ran\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   -P 5037 -s J2NPCX008612EAP shell mkdir -p '/Internal shared storage/Pictures''  exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'mkdir: '/Internal': Read-only file system
>   mkdir: 'shared': Read-only file system
>   mkdir: 'storage/Pictures': Permission denied'; Code: '1'

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are **private to your app, and other apps cannot access them (nor can the user, unless they have root access)**. This makes internal storage a good place for internal app data that the user doesn't need to directly access. The system provides a private directory on the file system for each app where you can organize any files your app needs.

So you need to change the destination to [`/data` or to `/sdcard`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)

If you need to be able to save the files into the Internal Storage - you will have to root your device first and copy the file via [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) command, it can be done via either [mobile:shell command](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/#mobile-shell) or via [run command](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Run%20Command%20(adb))